# Allowing sudo privileges, but not access to sites

Tags: sudo, parental-controls

Is it possible to make it so a user can use the sudo command in terminal, but not have access to sites other then those allowed through parental controls, without a third party system?

Comment: i think the real question should be why you trust one this much so you thinking about giving them sudo powers but don't trust them to not go on certain websites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By adjusting the *sudoers* file (*/etc/sudoers*) with `sudo visudo` it should be possible to accomplish this. It is a hell of a job and you need a profound knowledge of all commands to fine-tune this while avoiding errors and loopholes though.

You have to add the user to the *User privilege specification* section

```
...
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
...
```

Then use a whitelist (or a blacklist) of allowed (or disallowed) commands:

Examples:

whitelist

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
user    ALL=/usr/bin/nano,/usr/bin/opensnoop
```

blacklist

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
user    ALL=!/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy,!/usr/bin/passwd,!/usr/sbin/*
```

You may mix whitelist and blacklist.

Please check `man sudoers` how to simplify things or narrow things down by configuring *User, Runas, Host and Cmnd alias specifications*.

---

Check the accepted answer to the question [How to prevent sudo users from running specific commands?](https://superuser.com/a/735286/374285) for the pitfalls of configuring a simple command like `rnano` in the sudoers file.

Answer (score 1):

The two concepts are mutually exclusive.

Adding someone to the sudoers list effectively gives them the power to bypass any restriction you wish to impose on them.